# javascript replace for constructs like {... {..}... }

Tags: javascript, regex, curly-braces

I want to write a regexp for balanced braces constructs like

`{...}`, `{... {..}...}` and `{...{..{..}...}..{..}...}` where `...` means any text, which  has no '{' or '}' chars

If I do this:

```
   txt.replace(/\{[\s\S]+?}/g, function(s){return "_"+s+"_";})
```

the first `}` will be considered as end match, so 
 `{ { } }` will become `_{ { }_ }`

I want a regex to convert this to `_{ { } }_`

PS: the `function(s)` part is not from real code, just for example
PPS: I want to do this with regexps if it possible.
PPPS: Highest level of '{' braces included in the text is limited, to 3 or 4 usually

**UPDATE:** 
Thanks for comments, Let's limit the number of nested braces to 3. So:

`{ { { .. } .. { .. } }  .. { .. } }`

Comment: If you know how many braces there will be, you can do it. If not, regular expressions cannot do it.

Comment: what if there's a string with a brace in it?

Comment: An unknown/variable number of balanced parentheses are by definition not *regular* enough to be handled by regular expressions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Thanks for comments, Let's limit the number of nested braces to 3.

OK, that gives something that we can do with regular expressions. (There are such things as "extended" regular expressions, such as found in Perl or Python, that **can** match arbitrary nested braces, by using something called "backreferences". I don't know if Javascript's "regular expressions" support those, though.)

We build up the regular expression in pieces.

First, let's figure out what a chunk with **no** nested braces looks like:

```
[^{}]*
```

OK, that was easy. Any number of non-brace characters. :)

A construct with one level of braces, therefore, looks like

```
{[^{}]*}
```

since we want braces at the beginning and end, and nowhere else.

How about up to 2 levels?

Well, then we still have braces at beginning and end, and our content can be "any number of chunks of data, each of which has either 0 or 1 levels of braces".

So, we put together "0 or 1 levels of braces" by joining those two expressions with `|` (so that we match one or the other), and put parentheses around that (because we want to treat that as a whole unit) and a * afterward to denote "any number of this thing we just defined between the parentheses". Then braces go around the whole thing. That gives:

```
{({[^{}]*}|[^{}]*)*}
  ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^
exp. for   exp. for
1 level    0 levels
```

3 levels of braces are left as an exercise. :) Hint: We apply the same logic - braces enclose any number of chunks, each of which has up to 2 levels of braces.

Comment: `/ { ( { ( {[^{}]*}|[^{}]*)* }|[^{}]* )* }/` ? (some spaces added)

Comment: What should I do if my braces is not a one char braces, but actually a two: `{{` for opening brace and `}}` for closing brace ?

Comment: Your resulting regex should have, somewhere in the middle, a `(x|y|z)` grouping where x, y and z correspond to the three regexes created so far. If the braces are always `{{` and `}}`, then just replace the single braces in the regex with the double braces; that way you're treating them as a single unit.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions cannot match balanced text to arbitrary levels of nesting. At least, not without non-regular extensions.

But if the amount of nesting is limited, and you don't mind a fragile and obtuse solution to the problem, then you can make them work.

```
/{([^{}]*{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*}/
```

will match against one level of nested braces, and it should be (relatively) straightforward to extend that to the number of levels of nesting you require.

Comment: So, can you "relatively straightforward extend" this to two levels of nesting?

Comment: `/{([^{}]*{([^{}]*{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*})*[^{}]*}/`

Comment: You say "fragile". I want this code to be used by dozens of thousand users on gigabytes of text.

Comment: Note that this solution interprets the data at the lowest level as **alternating** chunks of single-braced and non-braced data, then renders the alternation as "any number of non-braced-followed-by-single-braced, then a final non-braced". This works (and may be more efficient) because non-braced chunks can be empty; but you might find the approach I described easier to understand.

Comment: @osgx: By "fragile" I mean that if your specification changes slightly, you're probably going to have to redo your regular expressions entirely. A more robust solution would be able to adapt to slightly different specifications with only minor changes. Additionally, regular expression matching is overkill for your use case - simply walking through the string keeping track of how many braces you've seen would be sufficient to achieve your goals, and *much* more performant.

Comment: @osgx, I assume Anon. means that **any** solution to the "limited" problem is necessarily "fragile and obtuse", because programmers inherently dislike these kinds of artificial limits. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_One_Infinity , and also the pages that are cited by the Wikipedia article.

Comment: My specifications are rather stable (they are from 2005). The code cited in the question is used for 5 years, but it breaks some formatting when used. It is not very critical.